# Magento 1.7 Advanced Search Our Of Order?

Tags: php, magento-1.7, advanced-search

I have a website and I am using Magento 1.7.2 cart. I am also utilizing the Advanced Search. My problem is when you select "All" from Power Watts under advanced search (http://www.webstertoolbox.com/index.php/catalogsearch/advanced/) then click search the product display page show up all messed up.

Here is my return page return.phtml code:

```
?>
<div class="page-title">
    <h1><?php echo $this->__('Catalog Advanced Search') ?></h1>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
<?php if($this->getResultCount()): ?>
    <p class="advanced-search-amount">
        <?php echo $this->helper('catalogsearch')->__('<strong>%d item(s)</strong> were     found using the following search criteria', $this->getResultCount()); ?>
    </p>
<?php else: ?>
    <p class="error-msg"><?php echo $this->helper('catalogsearch')->__('No items were     found using the following search criteria.');?> <a href="<?php echo $this->getFormUrl(); ?    >"><?php echo $this->helper('catalogsearch')->__('Modify your search'); ?></a></p>
<?php endif; ?>

<div class="advanced-search-summary">
    <?php $searchCriterias=$this->getSearchCriterias(); ?>
        <?php foreach (array('left', 'right') as $side): ?>
            <?php if(@$searchCriterias[$side]): ?>
                <ul>
                    <?php foreach($searchCriterias[$side] as $criteria): ?>
                        <li><strong><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->helper('catalog')->__($criteria['name'])); ?>:</strong> <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($criteria['value']); ?></li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php if($this->getResultCount()): ?>
        <p>
            <?php echo $this->helper('catalogsearch')->__("Don't see what you're lookingfor?"); ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getFormUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $this->helper('catalogsearch')->__('Modify your search'); ?></a>
        </p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php if($this->getResultCount()): ?>
<?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php $this->getSearchCriterias(); ?>
```

Here is my catalog.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">

    <default>
        <reference name="header">
            <block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="footer_links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalogsearch" ifconfig="catalog/seo/search_terms">
                <label>Search Terms</label>
                <url helper="catalogsearch/getSearchTermUrl" />
                <title>Search Terms</title>
            </action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalogsearch">
                <label>Advanced Search</label>
                <url helper="catalogsearch/getAdvancedSearchUrl" />
                <title>Advanced Search</title>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>

    <catalogsearch_result_index translate="label">
        <label>Quick Search Form</label>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3columns.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="catalogsearch/layer" name="catalogsearch.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalogsearch/result" name="search.result" template="catalogsearch/result.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list" name="search_result_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                    <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                        <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                    </block>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                    <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
                </block>
                <action method="setListOrders"/>
                <action method="setListModes"/>
                <action method="setListCollection"/>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalogsearch_result_index>

    <catalogsearch_advanced_index translate="label">
        <label>Advanced Search Form</label>
        <!-- Mage_Catalogsearch -->
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="catalogsearch"><title>Advanced Search</title></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><name>calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css</name><params/><!--<if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar-setup.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalogsearch/advanced_form" name="catalogsearch_advanced_form" template="catalogsearch/advanced/form.phtml"/>
            <block type="core/html_calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="page/js/calendar.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </catalogsearch_advanced_index>

<!--
Advanced search results
-->

    <catalogsearch_advanced_result translate="label">
        <label>Advanced Search Result</label>
        <update handle="page_two_columns_right" />
        <!-- Mage_Catalogsearch -->
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalogsearch/advanced_result" name="catalogsearch_advanced_result" template="catalogsearch/advanced/result.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list" name="search_result_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                    <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                        <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                    </block>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                    <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
                </block>
                <action method="setListOrders"/>
                <action method="setListModes"/>
                <action method="setListCollection"/>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalogsearch_advanced_result>

    <catalogsearch_term_popular translate="label">
        <label>Popular Search Terms</label>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="catalogsearch"><title>Search Terms</title></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalogsearch/term" name="seo.searchterm" template="catalogsearch/term.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </catalogsearch_term_popular>

</layout>
```

Why is this doing this and how can get this page back to default? The layout for some reason cuts off and I need to be like the products pages.

Here is the link to the products page see how this lays out fine: http://www.webstertoolbox.com/index.php/products/genlume-collection.html

You can find the site here: http://www.webstertoolbox.com/index.php/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?name=&sku=&power_wattage%5B%5D=57

Let me know if you need anything else?

Here is a photo of the product highlighted in Red: http://webstertoolbox.com/magento.jpg

Comment: could you explain in detail "display page show up all messed up" in the site ?

Comment: @balajimca well that's my problem. The products here: http://www.webstertoolbox.com/index.php/products/genlume-collection/sld-series.html show fine in line and in order. But when I do an advanced search the results page shows the products all over the place. I know this much when I switch my template back to Mageno's default template it doesn't do this. So some file in my template is messed up. I tried replacing the results page in my themes template category search folder using the default from magento and that didn't work either. So not sure if its CSS or a Magento file.

Comment: @balajimca If you go to my Search Products Menu Link and then under Power (Wattage) select "ALL" and search here what the page looks like: http://www.webstertoolbox.com/index.php/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?name=&sku=&power_wattage%5B%5D=57   Any suggestions why this is doing this and how do I fix it? Thanks!